# How to use Python dictionary to code this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have two tables (Pandas DataFrames), they look somewhat like this:

[image: tables]

The data is from 2 Airtable API calls. I converted them to DataFrames. 
The ids in table 1, `fields.Topics` are corresponding to table 2 `id` column. I want to put the `fields.Name` from table 2 in table 1 by mapping them to `fields.Topics`.

```
Topics_dict = dict(zip(Table2['id'] ,Table2['fields.Name']))
Table1.explode('fields.Topics')
Table1['Topic'] = Table1['fields.Topics'].map(Topics_dict)
```

I am having trouble mapping them. This gives error :

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: do you have pandas DataFrames? and please dont post images of data, but paste the data in your question so people can copy it

Comment: If you don't know how to use `lambda`, why don't you write a normal function first?

Comment: and why do you want to use lamda? you can explode table 1 and then join table 2

Comment: @luigigi Thank you for the edit. This is my first time using this platform and I did not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can explode `Topics`-column of table1. Then we set the index of both tables and then join table2 on table1. Then we groupby `Publisher` to recreate table1 format like this:

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame({'Publisher':['Jim', 'Jack', 'John'], 'Topics':[['a', 'b'], 'c', ['c','d','e']]})
table2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a', 'c', 'e'], 'Name':['Cupcake', 'Pastry', 'Brownie']})

result = (table1.explode('Topics')
      .set_index('Topics')
      .join(table2.set_index('id'))
      .reset_index()
      .groupby('Publisher').agg(list))

print(result)

               index                    Name
Publisher                                   
Jack             [c]                [Pastry]
Jim           [a, b]          [Cupcake, nan]
John       [c, d, e]  [Pastry, nan, Brownie]
```

Comment: NameError: name 'join' is not defined

Comment: what should i do with that comment? you need to be more specific if you want help. what exactly did you try?

Comment: Ok, you seem very rude. But thank you for your time. I figured it out.